# Google Maps custom marker - can the iframe accept one like the static maps?

Tags: api, google-maps, iframe

I was reading the static maps API, and it says you can include a custom marker in the GET params. You simply link to an image file.

I now have a second Google Map within an `iframe`, and was wondering if you can attach custom markers via the GET params to it? Here is the `src` attribute of the `iframe` currently.

```
http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&source=s_q&hl=en&geocode=&q=111+Fake+Street+Noosaville+Queensland+Australia&ie=UTF8&output=embed
```

I can't seem to find the documentation on how to do this, if possible.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know you cannot add custom marker icons on `maps.google.com`, but you should be able to add a marker with a custom label.

You may also be interested in checking out the following reference, which describes all the known parameters that can be passed to `maps.google.com`:

- [Mapki: Google Map Parameters](http://mapki.com/index.php?title=Google_Map_Parameters)

While this is not an official API, I think it is fair to say that these should be quite reliable, since they are the same parameters used for the permanent links in Google Maps.

---

On the other hand, you may want to consider using the [Google Maps API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/) instead. You will get all the capabilities you had with the Static Maps API (and more), and it will look pretty much the same as the iframe you are using right now.